# Check many URLs for availability with cURL

Tags: curl

I would like to test a long list of URLs for their availability. For this purpose i have built a small prototype with curl. I get the status code back and then decide what should happen. Is there a way to tune this process a little bit, maybe make it parallel?

```
#!/bin/bash

rm alive.txt dead.txt

while read URL; do
 response=$(curl -LI "${URL}" -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s --head --speed-limit 1 --speed-time 20 --connect-timeout 2)

 if [ "$response" -lt 400 ]; then
  echo "$URL" >> alive.txt
 else
  echo "$URL" >> dead.txt
 fi

done < blocklist.txt
```

Comment: research `xargs` and/or `gnu-parallel`, but neither are designed to manage network traffic. Requests for recommendations are off topic, so  please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: curl is a simple unix process.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm alive.txt dead.txt

GetUrlStatus() {
        url="$1"
        urlstatus=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out  '%{http_code}' "${url}" --max-time 2 --speed-limit 1 --speed-time 20 --connect-timeout 2)

        if [[ "$urlstatus" -eq "301" ]] || [[ "$urlstatus" -eq "302" ]] || [[ "$urlstatus" -eq "200" ]] ; then
         echo "$url" >> alive.txt
        else
         echo "$url" >> dead.txt
        fi
}

export -f GetUrlStatus

cat blocklist.txt | parallel -j20 -k GetUrlStatus
```